# How to hide a element/tag on modal dialog in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a problem about using modal dialog in bootstrap.
I have a button, when I click on this button, then I want a tag on modal dialog to hide (
eg : div class="radio published " is hidden).I used jquery but it doesn't run. Please help me. Thanks a lot!

I don't understand why my css has no effect to modal dialog.

```
 $("#change-status-modal .modal-body div.published").hide();
```

Code of button:

```
 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#change-status-modal" class="btn btn-default change-status">Change Status </a>
```

Code of modal dialog:

```
<div id="change-status-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div id="change-status-dialog" class="modal-dialog">
    <div th:fragment="change-status-form" class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Change Status</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Select a new status that you want to change.</p>
        <div class="radio published ">
          <input type="radio" name="status"  value="PUBLISHED" /> Published
        </div>
        <div class="radio draft ">
          <input type="radio" name="status" value="DRAFT" checked="checked" /> Draft
        </div>
        <div class="radio scheduled">
          <input type="radio" name="status" value="SCHEDULED" /> Scheduled
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" th:text="#{Cancel}">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" th:attr="data-action=@{__${ADMIN_PATH}__/articles/change-status}"  >Change</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to get it easier give the part, which should be hide some ID's. Then you can access them easily and add css property:

```
<a id="buttonHide" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#change-status-modal" class="btn btn-default change-status">Change Status </a>

$("#buttonHide").click(function(){$("#myParagraphToHide").css({"display": none})});
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, but It shows again immediately.

Comment: .css({"display": none !important})

Comment: I don't really understand why It stil shows again immediately!!